# manage of two different socket

Tags: qt, sockets

I have a server program developed in Qt

A computer can connect to the server with a Qt Application

A mobile phone (android programmed in Java) that can also connect to the server Qt

The management of data reception and transmission differs.

I want to know how to recognize the socket of the computer and the phone.

Thank you

Comment: You'll need some identification mechanism in your protocol. Let the clients request the type of data they want.

Comment: You can also use different ports for different protocols. What have you got so far?